# Looking for searchable code archives

Tags: project-hosting, search-engine

As part of research for a user group presentation I'm looking for usage examples of certain code constructs.

I'm looking for online source code repository collections that allow me to search inside the source code across the whole collection.

GitHub does it but it's a bit light on the sort of code I'm looking for.

Sourceforge searches only the project description text rather than the source code.

Any others I should try?